# IS there a way for creating a ruby gem that copy and paste some files and folders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, rubygems

I have a ruby gem and i need to add some folders inside it so when require the gem in my project the files and folders added automatically to my project

I tried to write a copy and paste code in my gem but when run the bundler in my project returned that the path not existed

Comment: Hard to work out what you're asking. Why aren't you just adding the files to your project? Why are you talking about this other gem?

Comment: I want to use this files in multiple projects for multiple users, so it will be hard to add this files each time for every one

Comment: I would be very annoyed when a gem writes files into my project just because I added it to the `Gemfile`. Or even worse, it is an indirect dependency and adds files to my project. I would prefer (and that seems to be the default) when the gem comes with a setup task that needs to run manually to finalize the gem setup.

Comment: Since this is tagged with `ruby-on-rails`, a custom [generator](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) seems like a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:**

Assuming you have a `my_gem` gem project with `/templates` folder inside it:

```rb
# in my_gem.rb 

module MyGem
  def self.setup_files(project_root)
    File.write(File.join(project_root, 'my_gem.txt'), 'The content of file')
    # or
    FileUtils.cp_r("#{__dir__}/templates/", project_root)
  end
end


# in your project

require 'my_gem'
MyGem.setup_files(Dir.pwd)

# or in Rails project
MyGem.setup_files(Rails.root)
```

Comment: can't use this solutions because i have big content of the files and i have big tree of folders

Comment: So, you can easily use FileUtils.cp (https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp) instead of File.write. The rest will the same.

Comment: @MohamedTurki your question says "some files and folders". You should be more specific if you think the amount of files / folders is significant to the solution.